# Insert VBA into Word from Excel

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

1. I have a spreadsheet that generates a word document, formats it, and
   then adds a bunch of text to the document, based on what was all
   selected and entered into the spreadsheet. All of this works great.
2. What I am trying to do is somehow insert `VBA` code into the Word document at the time it was being generated within Excel.

Here is the specific code that I am trying to insert - ultimately this needs to go into Word VBA:

```
Private Sub Document_Close()
    ActiveDocument.Saved = True
End Sub
```

I can’t seem to get `Excel` to insert this code into the `Word` document that is being generated. I know it is possible, but can’t figure it out. I tried several things and it accepts my code, but I have no idea where it is being inserted, because when I look for the inserted lines I can’t find them.

Here is the code that I am using to generate the `Word documen`t. Can someone please take a look and let me know how to insert the above code into this Document? Thanks for any help you can give.

```
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add

With wrdApp.Selection
‘A bunch of formatting code and text inputting is listed here for the word document.
End With

wrdApp.Visible = True
wrdApp.Activate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set Word to trust programmatic access to the `VBA` project then:

```
Sub ExceltoWord()
Dim strIn As String
strIn = "Private Sub Document_Close()" & Chr(10) & " ActiveDocument.Saved = True" & Chr(10) & "End Sub"
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wrddoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
wrddoc.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisDocument").CodeModule.AddFromString strIn
wrdApp.Visible = True
wrdApp.Activate
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This works great. Actually my other code was working too, I just didn't have the Trust VBA option turned on. Although the code you supplied is slightly simpler than my code, so I am going with your code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If the code you want to insert into Word is constant (as it probably should be), you could manually create a Word file with the code already in it and then use that file as a template instead of starting from a completely empty Word document.